# How does a static cast conserve a number's precision in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

After a long time without programming, I'm messing around with C++ for an assignment I have next month. I came upon the knowledge that variables can be overflown: specifically, float type variables will not hold as many decimals as double types. However, I tried this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> 


int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    cout << setprecision(20);

    double t(0.1);
    float g(0.1);
    cout << t << endl;
    cout << g << endl;
    static_cast<float>(t);
    cout << t << endl;


}
```

And, to my surprise, the precision in both the first and the final (double t and float t) were the same, whereas the precision in float g was less. This seems somewhat counter intuitive to me, how does static_cast preserve the precision in the numbers?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Casts are not in-situ operations. They *return* the converted value; they don't modify the original directly. Since you never store the result of your cast, doesn't do anything.

Comment: `float g(0.1f);` would be more correct

Answer (score 3):

That's because you didn't assign `static_cast`ed value to anything:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    cout << setprecision(20);

    double t(0.1);
    float g(0.1);
    cout << t << endl;
    cout << g << endl;
    g = static_cast<float>(t); // There was no assignment in your code
    cout << g << endl;
}
```

Output now:

```
0.10000000000000000555
0.10000000149011611938
0.10000000149011611938
```

Comment: Ah, I so hoped it wasn't a noob mistake. Thank you, regardless.

Comment: @DeltaAccel who among us didn't make a noob mistake in our lives? (;

Answer (score 3):

you didn't change the value of t.

using this below:

```
 cout << static_cast<float>(t) << endl;
```

or

```
t = static_cast<float>(t);  
  cout << t << endl;
```